# Change old link icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user

Change the old [image] icon to the new [image] SVG icon used in the editor nowadays.

Comment: + the image on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) page should be updated.

Comment: And finally, the style of bagdes should be the same on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) page.

Comment: The latter is unrelated to the site UI changes and should be a separate question

Comment: If you update the screenshot on the [CW help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki), you should definitely change that freehand circle to [red with a drop shadow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/271659).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link icon and community wiki: done (next build); crucially, I used the picker tool to preserve the exact shade of green, which is - I think we can all agree - the most important feature.