# Editor toolbar button for link in HELP

Tags: bug, help-center

As mentioned in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300291/change-old-link-icon) question the link icon in the editor was changed. But the link icon in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)(check below) still remains the same!!

[image: Editor toolbar button]

Answer (score -12):

The way to do this is by using CSS where you can:

```
<a href="http://www.anything.com" id="helplink">xxx</a>
```

CSS:

```
#helplink{
  background-image: url(images/cvI1y.png);
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question? What are we supposed to do? Add this style to Stylish? In that case the image can not be found. Maybe I miss something.

Comment: you need to add a stylesheet to your page and CSS above will add the image your hypelink

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: sorry about that. I misunderstand a question

Comment: The problem you have to solve is [shown in this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/M7Dlq.png). You can't fix that with css.